# Is 工作详细情况 similar to work experience?

Tags: translation, meaning

I´m working with Chinese resumes and I´ve found this expression

> 工作详细情况"

I´d like to know if it could be translated as work experience. Is it the same thing? Could 工作详细情况 work as a work experience section label inside a resume or does it refer to the job responsibilities? Is it normal to come across 工作详细情况 in Chinese resumes as a Section Title?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No.

Yes, it means work experience, but you will have to specify each job experience.

- 2004-2007 I worked as an HR manner and I ....(specify what you did as an HR manager )

Answer (score 2):

工作详细情况 means work experience in detail.

For work experience, some people may just list their previous job titles only, like this:

- 2000年 － 2003年  在XX公司任人力部职员
- 2004年 － 2009年  在YY公司任人力部主任
- 2010年 － 至今    在ZZ公司任华北区总经理

This looks too simplified, so in you resume, it is sepecified as 工作 **详细情况** , which means you will need to describe what you did and what you achieved in each job.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "工作经历", or less formally "工作经验", would be more appropriate. Baidu has a sample of a [resume](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E7%AE%80%E5%8E%86) written in Chinese:

> **工作经历**
>  2000年5月至今： 担任某瓷器公司的市场部业务员。
>   主要负责与经销商签定经销合同、办理产品的包装、运输、保险、货款结算、售后产品跟踪、市场反馈以及开拓新的销售渠道等。负责公司新业务员的培训，在实际工作中具体指导和协调业务员的销售工作，并多次受到公司的表扬。
>
> 1999年12月至2000年5月：在某公司做市场调查员。主要负责以电话形式向客户提取对产品的意见，并填写相应的表单转报给公司。

经验 translates directly to experience while 经历 refers to past experience. 工作情况 is usually taken to mean the conditions at work, while 工作详细情况 generally refers to the working conditions in detail.

In summary, I would recommend that you use "工作经历" in the heading for your resume.

Comment: I agree, and I think 工作经历 or 职业经历 is better than others.